# R data.table bin data (cut) for each group

Tags: r, data.table

```
> dt = data.table(A = rep(c('x','y'), each = 3), B = 1:6)
> dt
   A B
1: x 1
2: x 2
3: x 3
4: y 4
5: y 5
6: y 6
```

I want to bin the data for each group in A, ie the desired output should look like

```
   A B desired
1: x 1 [1,2]
2: x 2 [1,2]
3: x 3 (2,3]
4: y 4 [4,5]
5: y 5 [4,5]
6: y 6 (5,6]
```

but

```
> dt[, C := cut(B, 2, include.lowest = TRUE), by = A]
> dt
   A B     C
1: x 1 [4,5]
2: x 2 [4,5]
3: x 3 (5,6]
4: y 4 [4,5]
5: y 5 [4,5]
6: y 6 (5,6]
```

What is the correct way?

Comment: Wrapping `cut` with `as.character` seems to work

Comment: @alexis_laz, yes, it does. Thanks. I guess I know why it happens then. The C column is a factor column and the underlying factor levels are 1 and 2 for both group. If you like, please put it as an answer and I can accept it.

Comment: On the other hand `dt[, cut(B, 2, include.lowest = TRUE), by = A]` concatenates the "factor"s in a different way. I don't know but, probably, there is a more idiomatic way in "data.table" to create "C" rather than applying `as.character` by "A".