# Label quantile by group with varying group sizes

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation

**Within** my group (the "name" variable), I want cut the value into **quartile**. And **create a quartile label column** for variable "value". Since the group **size varies**, for the **quartile range** for different group **changes** as well. **But** below code, only cut the quartile by the overall value, resulting the **same quartile** **range** for all groups.

```
dt<-data.frame(name=c(rep('a',8),rep('b',4),rep('c',5)),value=c(1:8,1:4,1:5))
dt
dt.2<-dt%>% group_by(name)%>% mutate(newcol=
cut(value,breaks=quantile(value,probs=seq(0,1,0.25),na.rm=TRUE),include.lowest=TRUE))
dt.2
str(dt.2)
```

Data:

```
   name value
1     a     1
2     a     2
3     a     3
4     a     4
5     a     5
6     a     6
7     a     7
8     a     8
9     b     1
10    b     2
11    b     3
12    b     4
13    c     1
14    c     2
15    c     3
16    c     4
17    c     5
```

output from above code.
Update: the problem is not that newcol is factor but the necol has the same quartile range across all the different group. For example name b, the value is 1-4 but the quartile range has 3-5, which is derived from min(value) to max(value) regardless of the group.

```
 name value newcol
   <fctr> <int> <fctr>
1       a     1  [1,2]
2       a     2  [1,2]
3       a     3  (2,3]
4       a     4  (3,5]
5       a     5  (3,5]
6       a     6  (5,8]
7       a     7  (5,8]
8       a     8  (5,8]
9       b     1  [1,2]
10      b     2  [1,2]
11      b     3  (2,3]
12      b     4  (3,5]
13      c     1  [1,2]
14      c     2  [1,2]
15      c     3  (2,3]
16      c     4  (3,5]
17      c     5  (3,5]
```

Desired output

```
   name value newcol/quartile label

1       a     1  1
2       a     2  1
3       a     3  2
4       a     4  2
5       a     5  3
6       a     6  3
7       a     7  4
8       a     8  4
9       b     1  1
10      b     2  2
11      b     3  3
12      b     4  4
13      c     1  1
14      c     2  2
15      c     3  3
16      c     4  4
17      c     5  4
```

Comment: You could coerce to `numeric` as the `cut` output is `factor` i.e. `as.numeric(cut(...` or use `findInterval`

Comment: @akrun Thank for pointing out the way to get a numerical label for quartile. But the problem is the newcol has the same quartile range across all the different groups. I will update the question to clarify that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way you can do it, following the split-apply-combine framework.

```
dt<-data.frame(name=c(rep('a',8),rep('b',4),rep('c',5)),value=c(1:8,1:4,1:5))

split_dt <- lapply(split(dt, dt$name), 
                   transform, 
                   quantlabel = as.numeric(
cut(value, breaks = quantile(value, probs = seq(0,1,.25)), include.lowest = T)))

dt <- unsplit(split_dt, dt$name)

   name value quantlabel
1     a     1          1
2     a     2          1
3     a     3          2
4     a     4          2
5     a     5          3
6     a     6          3
7     a     7          4
8     a     8          4
9     b     1          1
10    b     2          2
11    b     3          3
12    b     4          4
13    c     1          1
14    c     2          1
15    c     3          2
16    c     4          3
17    c     5          4
```

**edit: there's a `data.table` way**

following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37054515/r-data-table-bin-data-cut-for-each-group), we can use the `data.table` package, if performance is a concern:

```
library(data.table)
dt<-data.frame(name=c(rep('a',8),rep('b',4),rep('c',5)),value=c(1:8,1:4,1:5))
dt.t <- as.data.table(dt)
dt.t[,quantlabels := as.numeric(cut(value, breaks = quantile(value, probs = seq(0,1,.25)), include.lowest = T)), name]

    name value quantlabels
 1:    a     1           1
 2:    a     2           1
 3:    a     3           2
 4:    a     4           2
 5:    a     5           3
 6:    a     6           3
 7:    a     7           4
 8:    a     8           4
 9:    b     1           1
10:    b     2           2
11:    b     3           3
12:    b     4           4
13:    c     1           1
14:    c     2           1
15:    c     3           2
16:    c     4           3
17:    c     5           4
```

**edit: and there's a `dplyr` way**

We can follow @akrun's advice and use `as.numeric` (which is what we've done for the other solutions):

```
dt %>%
    group_by(name) %>%
    mutate(quantlabel = 
               as.numeric(
                   cut(value, 
                       breaks = quantile(value, probs = seq(0,1,.25)), 
                       include.lowest = T)))
```

Note that if you instead wanted the labels themselves, use `as.character`:

```
dt %>%
    group_by(name) %>%
    mutate(quantlabel = as.character(cut(value, breaks = quantile(value, probs = seq(0,1,.25)), include.lowest = T)))

Source: local data frame [17 x 3]
Groups: name [3]

     name value quantlabel
   <fctr> <int>      <chr>
1       a     1   [1,2.75]
2       a     2   [1,2.75]
3       a     3 (2.75,4.5]
4       a     4 (2.75,4.5]
5       a     5 (4.5,6.25]
6       a     6 (4.5,6.25]
7       a     7   (6.25,8]
8       a     8   (6.25,8]
9       b     1   [1,1.75]
10      b     2 (1.75,2.5]
11      b     3 (2.5,3.25]
12      b     4   (3.25,4]
13      c     1      [1,2]
14      c     2      [1,2]
15      c     3      (2,3]
16      c     4      (3,4]
17      c     5      (4,5]
```

Comment: Thank you! Your code looks pretty similar to my code and it works. But I was wondering why the group_by here does not pass to cut in my code.

Comment: @Phdaml I'm not a `dplyr` expert so I'm not entirely sure why it wouldn't work.

Comment: I figured out why my group by is not working. I somehow unattached the dplyr package but no error shows after I  run the code.

Comment: What if the number of breaks is bigger than the number of observations? I set the data so that the observation for each group is bigger than 4 so a quartile is doable. Besides filter out the  case where number of observations is smaller than number of break, what else can I do to still give a smaller break number to them?